# Connect Desktop & Laptop to USB C Laptop Docking Station to Utilize Desktop Monitors for Both

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-computer, docking-station, usb-c, expansion-cards

I have an ASUS M32CD Desktop (Core i5, 8GB DDR4, 1TB, Windows 10) with Keyboard and Mouse and I want to connect to my desktop monitors using a Hiearcool USB C Hub,USB-C Laptop Docking Station,11 in 1 Triple Display Type C Adapter Compatiable for MacBook and Windows(2HDMI VGA PD3.0 SD TF Card. What is the solution for this? If the is solution is installing a USB C Expansion Card in my desktop, what USB C Expansion Card should I install?

ASUS M32CD Desktop
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01BGT69OE/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01BGT69OE)

Hiearcool USB C Hub,USB-C Laptop Docking Station
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07QNRM45T/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QNRM45T)